# How to patch all changed files before a commit in Git

Tags: git

I need to remove all trailing whitespaces before changed files will be committed. The question is how to do it?

Comment: Consider accepting answers on some of your questions, where applicable. You can do this by clicking the checkmark next to the correct answer in each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a good way to just automatically remove trailing whitespace at commit time (and I don't believe it'd be a good idea to do it if you could).

I've used a hook before to reject commits that add trailing whitespace, which worked well for me; create/add the following to `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and make it executable:

```
# Work out what to diff against
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

Answer (score 0):

Git by default warns about trailing whitespace, and can be configured to reject commits that add whitespace errors.

Removing the whitespace works only by changing the files and redoing the `git-add` stage -- while it would be possible to do this automatically on add, this would leave a working tree that is different than what is staged, so the files would still show up as "changed but not updated" in `git-status` output.

The easiest way to remove trailing whitespace is

```
sed -i -e 's/[:blank:]*$//' file.c ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually I decided to write gitadd command for that.

```
#!/bin/bash


# Number of arguments passed
argc=$#


if [ $argc -eq 0  ]; then
        argv=( $(git diff --name-only HEAD) )
else
        argv=( $@ )
fi

for file in "$argv"; do

        sed -i -e 's/^[[:blank:]]\+$//' $file

        git add $file # stage patched file

done
```